# confusion about i2c device driver

Tags: linux, driver, device, i2c

I know how to write an SMbus adapter driver for I2C but still unaware of the fact that whether or not this driver is sufficient to talk to or have my i2c sensor work with the linux machine or board, in case if I in particular want to insert my driver in to the kernel....

or in other words say I have some gyroscope to interface with ARM9, so is there still a lot to learn as far as writing an I2C driver is concerned or suffices well enough with the one mentioned above....Help me out please tripped over on this doubt....

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux, you should look for the i2c-tools package. You'll want i2c-detect or i2c-dump to do the i2c accesses.

To see if you can even see it connected.